# Check queries not used in a Oracle reports

Tags: oracle, report, oraclereports

I'm using Oracle Report Builder 9.0.4.1.0 and I have a heavy report that has defined a large number of queries. I think not all that queries are used in the report and are not linked to any layout object.
Is there a easy way to detect what queries (or other objects) aren't used at all in a specific report? Instead of delete the query, compile and run and verify one by one if are used or not?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is an easy way to do that, I don't know it. A long time ago, when Reports 1.x was used, report was saved in the database so you could write a query to fetch metadata you're interested in. I never did that, though, but - that would be an option. Now, all you have is a RDF (or a JSP) file.

However, a few suggestions, if I may.

Open Paper Layout Editor. Click the repeating frame and observe its property palette as it contains information about the group it belongs to. "Group" can be viewed in Data Model layout.

As there aren't that many repeating frames, you should be able to eliminate queries that don't have any frames, i.e. don't contribute to the final result.

---

Another option is to put a condition

```
WHERE 1 = 2
```

into every query so that they won't return any rows. Run the report and check what's missing - then remove that condition so that you'd get values. Move on to second query, and so forth. That's a little bit tedious and time consuming, but should still be faster than deleting queries.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation. That's an alternative, of course. But I don't know very well this report so it's difficult for me to check if the data can be showed or not. That's why the alternative of deleting and compile/run is more reliable for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a report results to an XML file. Each query with data will contain something in XML-s tags.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tItz.png)